# Plivo getting UUID of call recording

Tags: plivo

I'm using the following code to dial out and record the call.

```
<Response>
<Record action="http://foo.com/get_recording/" startOnDialAnswer="true" redirect="false" />
<Dial>
    <Number>15551234567</Number>
</Dial>
```

However, the action url http://foo.com/get_recording/ receives only the following parameters, which does not include the UUID of the call. So I do not know which uuid does the call recording file belong to.

```
callbackUrl Request Parameters
```

The following parameters are sent to the callbackUrl

```
Parameter   Description
RecordUrl   Complete path to the recorded file URL.
RecordingDuration   Duration of recording in seconds.
RecordingDurationMs Duration of recording in milliseconds.
RecordingStartMs    When the recording started (epoch time UTC) in milliseconds.
RecordingEndMs  When the recording ended (epoch time UTC) in milliseconds.
RecordingID Recording ID of the file.
```

Any help on associating uuid with record_id would be appreciated. Tried writing to support but still awaiting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick!

Before you return the Dial XML, try capturing the callUUID in the request param you receive and append it with record action URL like a GET param dynamically. make your action method as GET

```
<Response>
<Record action="http://foo.com/get_recording/?callUUID=<uuid>" startOnDialAnswer="true" redirect="false" />
<Dial>
    <Number>15551234567</Number>
</Dial>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

Call UUID is present in the [Answer URL](https://www.plivo.com/docs/xml/request/#voice-calls) that returns your XML (Record and Dial) and the Recording ID is present in the Record action and Record callback URL. You could use the [Get Recording API](https://www.plivo.com/docs/api/recording/#list-a-specific-recording) to link a Call UUID to a Recording ID.